# Install more recent (or latest) Git version in Debian 9

Tags: git, debian, upgrade

I want to install Git on Debian 9.
I ran `apt install git-all` as it says on [Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) site but it installed version `2.11.0`.

I thought that there was a need for packages update, but `apt-get update` and `apt-get upgrade` didn't change anything. It appears that this Git version is the latest stable for Debian 9.

I want to use a more recent Git version. What is the best I can do?

Comment: This question belongs on superuser.com, but the short answer is: point your system at a later set of packages. The official release for your system *is* Git 2.11.0. Adding other repositories (these aren't *Git* repositories, they're Debian *package* repositories) will let you use a later-than-official-release version that someone has provided.

Comment: Debian 9 is way past its useful life for modern development. There is nothing to prevent you from _compiling_ a new version of Git (or finding someone who has already done that) but the absolutely simplest solution is to use a version of Debian which actually receives updates. Even then, your expectations are probably not going to be fulfilled (the current version of Debian, version 11 aka "Bullseye", ships Git 2.30.2 -- package version 1:2.30.2-1 -- whereas upstream is up to 2.33.1 which will only be available in the next version of Debian, if even then).

Comment: https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=git&searchon=names&section=all&suite=buster-backports has backported 2.30 packages for Buster (Debian 10); more generally, try https://backports.debian.org/Packages/ but currently that's the only hit for `git`.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, every answer contain useful info. I am a new Debian user, so all this info is helpful. What I end up doing, was to follow the instructions and install Git from source. Now the `git --version` replies with `2.33.1` I will post the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to run the latest Git version, I followed the instructions on **Installing from Source** on the official Git [site](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git).

Answer (score 9):

Maybe a [*backports*](https://backports.debian.org/Instructions/) version for the Debian *release* you are using provides a more recent git version which satisfies your requirements.

Taking the Debian 11 (*bullseye*) release as an example, [*bullseye*'s default *git* package is on version `2.30.x`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/git), whereas [`bullseye-backport`'s *git* is on version `2.34.x`](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye-backports/git). This more recent *git* version is especially desirable as it allows to [sign commits with SSH keys](https://calebhearth.com/sign-git-with-ssh).

First you need to add the *bullseye-backports* package source to your *bullseye* system <sup>(I don't know if e.g. the older *stretch* would allow to use *bullseye-backports*)</sup>, then after an `apt update`, you will be able to install the *backports* *git* package:

```bash
echo "deb http://deb.debian.org/debian bullseye-backports main" >/etc/apt/sources.list.d/bullseye-backports.list

apt update
apt install git/bullseye-backports
```

Comment: I had come across this solution when I was looking into it, but I try to avoid backports because their packages are a bit less tested. The main reason I use Debian is because of their stability. But in this case, since we are talking about `git` I don't think there would be a problem. Thank you.