# error: unsupported value for gpg.format: ssh

Tags: git, git-commit, ssh-keys

Trying to setup git commit signing on my Debian box. I already have this setup on my windows box and it works fine. Not so much on my Debian box. There I get the following error when I try to commit:

```
siggib@htzn:/var/www/phpdemo$ git commit -m "tweak"
error: unsupported value for gpg.format: ssh
fatal: bad config variable 'gpg.format' in file '/home/siggib/.gitconfig' at line 6
```

Here what my config looks like

```
siggib@htzn:/var/www/phpdemo$ git config --list
user.name=siggib@htzn
user.email=siggib007@users.noreply.github.com
user.signingkey=ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC.....
gpg.format=ssh
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
remote.origin.url=https://github.com/siggib007/phptest.git
remote.origin.fetch=+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
branch.master.remote=origin
branch.master.merge=refs/heads/master
siggib@htzn:/var/www/phpdemo$
```

I tried to google this and found nothing useful, also tried searching here with same results. Anyone have any good pointers for me?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turns out SSH signing is not available in the default git version in Debian 11. Had to follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/74528937/8549454 to install a more up to date git version.

Answer (score 31):

SSH signing is only available with `git>=2.34` ([changelog](https://lore.kernel.org/git/xmqq8rxpgwki.fsf@gitster.g/)). You likely have an older version.

You can check like this:

```
$ git --version
git version 2.25.1
```

### Update git

If you are on Ubuntu, you can get a more recent version like this:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Comment: To upgrade Git on RHEL, you can use Homebrew: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75761468/658497

Comment: Update for Windows :
$git update-git-for-windows

Answer (score 0):

Check you git version installed on your machine. It is supported on and above git version 2.34. Upgrading git version will solve problem